className don't update with useState
I tried to make a random color changer screen, but for some reason every time the button is pressed, it won't work. Here is the code:
"use client"
import { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

function randomColor() {
    const hexa = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    return "#" + hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)] +
                 hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)] +
                 hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)] +
                 hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)] +
                 hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)] +
                 hexa[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)]
}

const ColorFlipper = (): ReactElement => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("#ff0000");
    function updateColor() {
        setColor(randomColor())
        console.log(color)
    }
    return (
        <div className={`flex bg-[${color}] h-full w-full`}>
            <button onClick={updateColor} className="w-1/3 h-1/3">
                Alterar cor
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ColorFlipper

i tried trading the variable "color" for an hexadecimal string and it worked when i revert the trade, but when the variable changes the background return to his original color

As far as I know, you can't do it using Tailwind CSS; you can use style instead.

This could help: Template literal not working correctly with Tailwind CSS.
